# Add a background image to shape in XML Android

Tags: android, android-xml

How do you add a background image to a shape? The code I tried below but no success:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
//here is where i need to set the image
<solid android:color="@drawable/button_image"/>
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
 </shape>
```

Comment: You need to extend and create a custom shaped class. Look into RoundedImageView for example. It creates a round imageview so whatever iamge you set as background to it, it will appear as rounded

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Use following `layerlist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <corners
                 android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
         </shape>
   </item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_here" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks,this did work however the edges are no longer rounded?

Comment: do you want Image with round edges?? because it seems your shape does not have any color

Comment: My shape did have a white color and rounded edges. I thought the rounded edges would remain if I removed the color and used an image instead. If this is not possible that is ok

Comment: so image with rounded corners , not possible?

Comment: It is possible but you need to programmatically round the corners of the image. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: how can I make the background the same size as the layout? Because with the above the background stretches the full screen and not within the layout width/height.

Comment: Is this possible to have the image item set dynamically? I don't have my image in a drawable folder

Comment: I does not work when the image is a vector asset (xml) though

Comment: The corners are not rounded

Comment: This worked like a charm for a simple flavour thing i wanted to achieve for a drawable background.

Answer (score 229):

I used the following for a drawable image with a circular background.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_select"
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="20dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Here is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: Is there something to set the gravity of the image.

Comment: @SagarDevanga for the drawable in the code above or when you include the image in your layout?

Comment: Firstly, I tried to use height and width to set the internal icon to 24dp (its actual size). This resized perfectly on the Preview in AS but had no effect on the tablet. Therefore I used your method. I set the height and width of the shape to 40dp and then top, bottom, left and right of the icon item to 8dp each. (40-24)/2=8. However, the resulting image looks the right size but is blurry, which I suspect is due to some kind of re-sizing of the PNG. Any suggestions?

Comment: TLDR; how would you create your image above with a 40dp diameter circle and a 24dp icon without losing image quality?

Comment: @LukeAllison how are you adding the icon to you UI and how big is the image that you are placing in the oval?

Comment: I solved my problem by using a better method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773226/icon-image-in-circle-shape-is-blurry/35773744#35773744

Comment: Is would have looked awesome with a shadow

Comment: well done, thanks  @SagarDevanga you can set gravity as well  android:gravity="center"

Comment: What about this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100470/android-buttons-with-shape-background-or-image

Comment: This actually just creates a round background with the square icon inside it.  This requires the dimensions of the icon to be smaller than the diameter of the circle.  If you want the icon to scale to be larger, this won't work.

Comment: @jungledev share what code you have. The image posted is what it generates. Perhaps your drawable is different.

Comment: @RayHunter, I was able to create the shape you posted with your code.  What I'm saying is that your code doesn't do what I need to do.  I need to round the corners of an icon (in other words, *decrease* the area of the icon).  What your code does is that it adds a round shape to the icon, thus enlarging the total area of it.  This matters if you need the icon image to be a certain size proportional to its dimensions.

Comment: @jungledev have you posted a question? If so, can you share the link to the question. I have created rounded corners on icons.

Answer (score 21):

This is a circle shape with icon inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ok_icon"/>
    <item>
        <shape
                android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/button_grey"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: more perfect for who want to show caret image and border

Answer (score 10):

This is a corner image :

**1- overlay drawable by stroke**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_main_blue"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <item>
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="5dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>

    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**2- hide the image inside a corner background**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="#1D1D19" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/movie_card_place_holder"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</layer-list>
```

Comment: this is just color overlay the drawable item. for who need image with stroke, this is perfect solution

Answer (score 5):

## I used the following for a drawable image with a border.

### First make a .xml file with this code in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/orange"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:top="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp"
    android:right="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/messages" //here messages is my image name, please give here your image name.
    android:bottom="15dp"
    android:left="15dp"
    android:right="15dp"
    android:top="15dp"/>
```

### Second make a view .xml file in layout folder and call the above .xml file with this way

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/merchant_circle" />  // here merchant_circle will be your first .xml file name
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another most easy way to get a custom shape for your image (Image View). It may be helpful for someone. It's just a single line code.

First you need to add a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mafstech.libs:mafs-image-shape:1.0.4'   
}
```

And then just write a line of code like this:

```
Shaper.shape(context, 
       R.drawable.your_original_image_which_will_be_displayed, 
       R.drawable.shaped_image_your_original_image_will_get_this_images_shape,
       imageView,
       height, 
       weight);
```