# Show image in rectangle?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to show image in rectangle tilted to 90 deg. How i can do this ?

[image]

In this frame i want to show image

please give me some solutions.

Thanks.

Comment: I see a square. Tilted at 45°...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android

Comment: @BobMalooga square is a subclass of rectangle :)

Comment: @Ahmad Dwaik 'Warlock': Sure. But just to be precise (OMG! I'm professionally deformed!!)... ;)

Comment: @BobMalooga and I forgot about angles, it's 45 as you said.

Answer (score 3):

you could create a 45d animation and apply it to your ImageView, like this:

```
    ImageView image= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    // Create 45d animaion
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 45f, image.getPivotX(), image.getPivotY());

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(1);               
    an.setRepeatCount(0);                
    an.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); 
    an.setFillAfter(true);               

    // Aplly animation to image
    image.setAnimation(an);
```

Answer (score 1):

With API >= 11

```
mImageView.setRotation(angle)
```

Another Method :

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId);
Options o = getSize(this, R.drawable.yourImage);
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.postRotate(angle, o.outWidth/2, o.outHeight/2);
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
img.setImageMatrix(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method.

```
public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);

    // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For All APIs
Place ImageView in your Layout XML, and set An Animation for it in the onCreate() of your Activity like that :

```
float rotationDegree = -45; //You can change if you need.
        Animation anim = new RotateAnimation(0,rotationDegree);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        imageView.startAnimation(anim);
```