# How to use image for background of shape?

Tags: android

I have a shape (rectangle) for ListItem selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   android:shape="rectangle" >
<solid android:color="#eef0f3" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

It's rectangle with color #eef0f3, but I need use background image instead of:

```
<solid android:color="#eef0f3" />
```

How can I to do this?

Comment: may this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a layer-list instead of a shape.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_image" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                 android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
                 android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
                 android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
                 android:topRightRadius="4dp"/>
         </shape>
   </item>
```

You will also need to add rounded corners to the image. To do this, look up:

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners)