# Xamarin , http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:state_pressed is not declared

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

it gives me error on state_pressed , android:color, android:width is not declared.

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
          <solid
              android:color="#ef4444" />
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp"
              android:color="#992f2f" />
          <corners
              android:radius="6dp" />
          <padding
              android:left="10dp"
              android:top="10dp"
              android:right="10dp"
              android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>

    </selector>
```

Comment: this happens while building or debuging? where do you call this state?

Comment: it gives me error ( state_pressed in not declared in "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" )

Comment: For those how have the same problem: from @usman [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055702/the-attribute-is-not-declared-android-on-basic-xml-attributes/39780611#39780611)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in which context that you are using this selector, but apply to a button it works fine:

[image]

#### layout/Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_selector"
        android:text="StackoverFlow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### drawable/bg_selector (your axml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
      <solid
          android:color="#ef4444" />
      <stroke
          android:width="1dp"
          android:color="#992f2f" />
      <corners
          android:radius="6dp" />
      <padding
          android:left="10dp"
          android:top="10dp"
          android:right="10dp"
          android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: This is NOT an answer. You can leave a comment saying that it works fine in your part or that you cant reproduce the error. How on earth your answer can help me that have the same problem!

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε that selector applied to the **background** of a Button works (it is valid syntax for a selector for that usage), applied elsewhere it may not, depends upon the context

Comment: The problem was that two schema files were missing from the schema folder in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. But I started a new project and started to copy and paste the same code from the old project and it worked.
Try it may be this is the only possible solution.