# AXML attributes not declared - Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm working on a VS2017 Enterprise Xamarin Android project and I'm using AXML designer to design my activities. I get a lot of messages as you see below, many standard attributes are not declared.

[image]

I tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132223/5786039 and its 6th comment.
- Changing my Android-SDK from 23 to 19 and 14.
- Updating my JDK from 7 to 8.
- Reinstalling Xamarin tools.

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create any folder in your pc, copy  [`android-layout-xml.xsd`](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/android-layout-xml.xsd) and [`schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd`](https://github.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/blob/master/schemas.android.com.apk.res.android.xsd) to this folder.
2. Open your project->open xml menu->schemas->remove the two items in below image:

[image]

3. Reference the two downloaded files to your schema.

**Notes: it will temporarily fix the designer error. but it will disable some of the 
auto-filling intellisense functionality (ex: auto-fill of `@+id/`). And reopen your axml with designer will also lead to auto-reference of the old `xsd` files.**

So considering the above truths. I would suggest you **use Android studio to finish the layout codes, then copy it to Visual Studio** or u**se Xamarin Studio if you have a Mac**. These errors won't have any impact on building/compilation of your project.

Comment: After one hour of searching for xml menu, it worked. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks.