# Android buttons with shape background or image

Tags: android, shapes

I want to create a button in an Android application which will be round with a color of my choosing and a plus sign as its text.

Is it better (in terms of space, efficiency etc.) to create an image of the above description and set it as a background image, or it it better to make a shape with a color and add that as a background?

Comment: Use Images, if you are not required to change that background color at runtime like theme change.

Comment: @MKJParekh on the other hand, I can also create 2 images with different background colors and just switch between them during runtime, meaning that I could use them even when needing to change the color.

Comment: I suppose you don't have a real programming question but what you have is a point of disussion, please consider using any of Android chat room whichever is live.  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ and once you are satisfied you can delete your question.

Comment: @YonatanNir it would be better to create the shape as an image and then add the images to your android application. I would only do code if there is something that you need that cannot be done with an image.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can create a circle shape with the help of shape drawable, but the better way to do this is to use the **FloatingActionButton** which is circular in shape and you can provide the icon of your choice.

Comment: The question is if I should even use a background image or just use the floating action button and only give it a background color and text

Answer (score 0):

```
    -First of You create drawable xml
    -ic_round_shape_background
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
      <solid android:color="#000" /><!--color code which you are use instead #000-->
      <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
          android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
          android:topRightRadius="8dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>
    </shape>

  //Create xml and use background like below
    activity_main.xml

     <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/ic_round_shape_background"
          />
```

Comment: I didn't ask HOW to do it. I asked what is the way that it SHOULD be done - via image or via code.

Comment: Both You Can Done but You should use via code to better performence

Answer (score 0):

**please try the below code**.

create a **background.xml** in **drawable** folder and paste this code.

`

```
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></stroke>

<padding
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="5dp"></padding>

<corners android:radius="5dp"></corners>
```

`

in **Layout**

`<LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/place_holder"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/background"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">`

```
                   ` <ImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/image" />


                </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: I didn't ask HOW to do it. I asked what is the way that it SHOULD be done - via image or via code.