# How to modify a drawable in a Resource File?

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources, drawable

I'd like to modify already existing drawable objects in an external resource-file, like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <drawable name="replyIcon" >
            <!--
            get icon from resources
            set color filter
            ...
            -->
        </drawable>
    </resources>
```

Is it possible? Because Android Studio suggests me "drawable" when I input an "<" inside a "< resources>"-file where I can also add style- and color- tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a background image to shape in XML Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

> In android you are able to create drawable Resources by following
>   steps:-

- Firstly, Right Click on the `drawable` Directory.
- After that Go New > Drawable resource file.
- After that New Resource file dialog box open on your computer screen. Enter File name in the text box and then press OK.
- finally that your `drawable` resource `XML` file will be created

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer :)

Comment: Maybe the formulation of my question is not exactly enough. I'd like to outsource the style / settings / ... of already existing drawables in an Resource file. Because Android Studio suggest me "drawable" in "<resources>" when input "<", but it suggest me nothing when I do it inside the "<drawable> </drawable>".

Comment: you may achieve this in your java code, by accessing resources over there.