# Fitting an image to xml shape

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am a beginner to android studio and I need to fit a `png` image to a shape I defined in res/drawable as an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <padding android:left="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp" />

    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="150dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

The shape looks like this,

[image]

I need to fit a rectangular image to it but don't know how to do so. The output should somewhat look like this

[image]

**Related**: [Add a background image to shape in XML Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android) I have tried using the code in the link but no luck.

**Edit**: The `activity_main.xml` file with ImageView is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The output of the above file is,

[image]

Comment: did you use that shape as a background to the View that you want to make rounded?

Comment: Yes, I used the shape as background in the ImageView in `mainActivity.xml`

Comment: So what is the problem then? You only said I need to do this, but you did not add what problem you're facing

Comment: I am sorry if the question was unclear. I have just started to learn android studio and I don't know how to fit the image to the shape I defined in xml.

Comment: You don't have to fit the Image. You need to set that shape as background, and then set the image to imageview using any image loading library or src tag of imageview

Comment: Doing so just puts the image over the shape but it does not fit inside the shape. That is the image remains rectangle and shape remains curved.

Comment: edit your question and add your XML file

Comment: @PrachiSingh not correct. Check the image he uploaded properly