# How to set background image to shape?

Tags: android, imageview, shapes

I have a shape. I am using a random color to fill the shape.

[image]

I have an image which needs to be set for the background of this shape. (I am just thinking it should be background. May be I am using wrong words. )

Result should be something like this (note the image at the background).

[image]

Comment: Check this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android

Comment: @ChrisPapantonis thanks for sharing. Unfortunately, they did not help.

Comment: I would like to know what was the downvote for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across with this library. `RoundedImageView` [Github link](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

All I needed to do was:

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_card_head_bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:riv_corner_radius="90dip"
        app:riv_mutate_background="true"
        app:riv_corner_radius_bottom_left="50dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you that library which you can custom corners , shape and other things and then you can put your image view inside it and then you'll have your view

here is the link 
https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

Comment: I'm using it and it's working well with me what is the issue is appearing to you

Comment: I used to library as they instructed in Github, but there is no change at all. The code compiles but nothing changes. I just see the rectangles only. None of the effects/shape changes offered by this library is working. I have no idea what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set src of your image view to those white things you have, then you will have your shape as background and this pattern on it as well.
use android:src

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an image within a shape, Try this,

shape.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="56dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now set the shape for a **layout**, then add the image that you want in image view then adjust the **alpha** value to show both shape and image,

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_image"      
        android:alpha=".2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[Output will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1HOe.png)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I am losing image quality due to `alpha`. Not really what I wanted .