# How to use image as backgroung image using only View Tag in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

i need to show images in layout but only using **view tag** not image view tag in android studio.but i have already use **background tag** for oval shape?

Comment: What's wrong with `ImageView`? If you'd explain it less abstract, it might be easier to answer.

Comment: Look into LayerList. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android

Comment: martin zeitler its a assignment that use only view tag for oval images and repeat it with recycler view.

Comment: qwerty its helpful to understand how to demonstrate for my use.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your use case because you didn't post any code. ;-)
Delete the solid to make the oval transparent.
Move the item (oval/image) which you would like to be in the background to the first position.
Try this xml for your drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```